# Obtaining the object pointed to by a double pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

If I have an iterator `list<Tree_Node*>::iterator iter`, for user-defined class `Tree_Node`, how do I return the object that a `Tree_Node*` points by going through the iterator? It's basically a pointer to a pointer, is it not?

Answer (score 0):

You dereference the iterator to get to the `Tree_Node*` object, then dereference that to get to the `Tree_Node`:

```
**iter
```

Let's say you have a member `Tree_Node::x`, you could refer to it as:

```
(**iter).x
(*iter)->x
```

> It's basically a pointer to a pointer, is it not?

In C++ the iterator abstraction is intended to have an API much like a pointer... doesn't really matter how they're implemented, though for many containers it will be a pointer.

Comment: For the list that I have, the only time I add things to it is using an `add()` function. In the function, I define a Tree_Node* to add to it, and that has a name, but I only do that to avoid using `new` and having to worry about clean-up. Outside of the function, that name means nothing. I plan on accessing each element of the list using a `for` loop. Since I can't directly use the (**iter).x format you gave, should I just temporarily assign each element the iterator's pointer (i.e. the `Tree_Node*`) to a variable so that I have a name to use? Or is there a better way to do this in the loop?

Comment: You can do something like `for (auto& p : my_list) p->tree_node_operation();` - that way `p` is the name given to each successive iterator value for use within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, you would do:

```
for(auto node : tree)
    cout << node->data;
```

Or in older versions:

```
for(list<Tree_Node*>::iterator node = tree.begin(); node != tree.end(); node++)
    cout << (*node)->data;
```

Answer (score 0):

> It's basically a pointer to a pointer, is it not?

The abstraction is the other way around: A pointer is a special type of iterator (and the thing that presumably iterators were modeled after), while an iterator is an abstraction. But you conclusion is right, just as with pointer to pointer you can do:

```
list<Tree_Node*>::iterator iter;
// assign something to iter
Tree_Node* ptr = *iter;
Tree_Node& node = *ptr;
```

Or short:

```
Tree_Node& node = **iter;
```

Comment: Interesting. So can you give me an example of an iterator that ISN'T a pointer? Having used almost nothing but pointers this semester it's hard to imagine another method of indirect object access.

Comment: @UnworthyToast: The iterator we are using here is such an example already. `std::list<T>` implements a linked list, so each of it's nodes has to contain pointers to the next and previous elements. Also, they can't always be held in contiguous memory. The `std::list<T>::iterator` probably uses pointers internally but, e.g. dereferencing does not give you the list's node, but the held content. `operator++()` does not increment the internal pointer, but set it to the one found in the nodes "next"-field.

Comment: Aha! This has always confused me but I think I get it now. So what you're saying is that iterators are simply an abstract data type modeled after pointers, and in fact they often are pointers just with done extra overloaded operators. But even when they themselves aren't pointers they are usually structures that rely on pointers in some fashion, as in this example here. Do I have that right?

Comment: @UnworthyToast: Yes, you got the idea. I don't think its right to call the operators 'overloaded' though, because most of them are simply functions of the iterator class (yes, the iterator is a special class, made explicitly for `std::list`).